# '?attr/colorControlActivated' not found in Android Studio preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am using the following code for floating Edit text.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/username_text_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/searchbtn"
                android:contentDescription="Using for Floating label">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editphone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/inputNumber"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="15" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

But it's not rendering in preview and getting following rendering issue in android studio.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Attribute '?attr/colorControlActivated' not found. Are you using the right theme?
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:76)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColorStateList(ResourceHelper.java:155)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getColor(BridgeTypedArray.java:299)
at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextAppearance(CollapsingTextHelper.java:191)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(TextInputLayout.java:270)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:111)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:82)
```

Comment: have you defined "colorControlActivated" it app theme?

Comment: where should I add it in the code?

Comment: show your app's gradle build dependencies